# OS X Apache *.php execute when domain is localhost but downloads file otherwise.

Tags: php, apache, localhost, osx-leopard

The setup:

On a **Mac OS X 10.5.8**, with the original **Apache 2.2**, where the only change is to uncomment

```
LoadModule php5_module
```

In the `_DocumentRoot_` dir, `/Library/Webserver/Documents/`, in a file named `info.php`, write:

```
<? php phpinfo(); ?>
```

The problem:

Request `http://localhost/info.php` and the response is the output from the function (i.e. PHP executed the file).

However, request from domain `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.1.x` and the response is the content of the file, w/ a header of Content-Type `application/x-httpd-php`.

The file is always found via the request, so it's not a hosts mapping problem.  However, it's treated as an executable only when the request is for domain localhost. There are no virtual hosts set up in the apache conf, so I figure the behaviour should be the same regardless of the domain.

Any idea how to remedy this so that I could use this server on my LAN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but do you have any allow/deny from all settings on your mod_php module's configuration?  I'm not sure if it allows that or not.

The reason I ask is because today I wound up tracking down an issue with a preconfigured Apache instance where mod_proxy was set to only allow on requests from localhost.  Switching it to allow requests from 10.* fixed the problem of another machine on the network correctly proxying.

Comment: Thanks, but no cigar. I don't see where I could configure mod_php.  There's no php.ini by default on the OSX installation of php5. I don't see what I could change to that at present.

Comment: Also, theotherian, the non-localhost domains don't end up calling php, it seems -- apache assigns a header type but doesn't seem to hand the file over to php to process.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the virtual hosts section of the httpd.confg? Is there anything there that sets the PHP filetype? In either case `AddHandler php5-script php` should be somewhere in the .conf.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There are no virtual hosts set up (the include is commented out by default).  I don't see any "AddHandler php5-script php" in any conf, yet localhost/info.php executes, so it's not the issue.  I added your suggested line and I still get the wonky behaviour.

Comment: Do you restart httpd after changing settings? Just making sure.